# How to create a Self-signed certificate for intranet

Tags: linux, self-signed-certificate

I'm struggeling a few days with a self-sign certificate on Linux that Google Chrome or other browsers won't accept the certificate. Access to myintranet is only available local or via VPN.

**DNS name 'myintranet'. LAMP Server IP 192.168.222.16**

What I've got so far:

1. **Creating a configuration file**

   ```
   [req]
   default_bits = 2048
   prompt = no
   default_md = sha256
   x509_extensions = v3_req
   distinguished_name = dn

   [dn]
   C = AT
   ST = MyState
   L = MyCity
   O = MyOrg
   emailAddress = email@mydomain.com 
   CN = myintranet

   [v3_req]
   subjectAltName = @alt_names

   [alt_names]
   DNS.1 = myintranet
   DNS.2 = 192.168.222.16
   ```
2. **Create certificate**

   ```
   openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout mykey.key -days 3560 -out mycert.crt -config configuration.conf
   ```
3. **Create pfx file**

   ```
   openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -out mypfx.pfx -inkey mykey.key -in mycert.crt"
   ```
4. **Enable SSL**

   ```
   a2ensite default-ssl.conf
   ```
5. **Change path from crt and key in /etc/apache2/default-ssl.conf**

   ```
   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
       <VirtualHost _default_:443>
           ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
           ServerName 192.168.222.16
           ServerAlias 192.168.222.16
           DocumentRoot /var/www/html

           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

           SSLEngine on

           SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mycert.crt
           SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mykey.key

           ...
   ```
6. **Restart Server**

   ```
   apache2ctl restart
   ```
7. **Download mycert.crt and install on Windows**

If I open https://myintranet or https://192.168.222.16 on chrome it shows the red warning "not secure". In the certificate details

```
"Certification status"
This certificate is valid.
```

In can't find the "alt_names" in the certificate details but I don't know if this is my problem.

Comment: Hello, your question is that you want a secure celf signed certificate ?

Comment: Have you added the public certificate to the client’s trust store (category trusted)?